# cannot resolve symbol and method

Tags: java, android, android-sdk-manager, cannot-find-symbol

My android studio version is 2.3.3

```
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 25
        buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.newstest"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 25
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
...
dependencies {
            compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
            androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
                exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
            })
            compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+'
            compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

            compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.+'
            compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:+'
            testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'}
```

I have downloaded SDK platform versions from 4.0 to 8.0, enabled everything in 'SDK Update Sites' panel and installed 'support repositories', 'android sdk build-tools','android sdk platform-tools','android sdk tools','documentation for android sdk' and even'google play services' and selected Android SDK location correctly. I use Android Studio embedded JDK.

But when I want to see the implementation of 'onCreate()' method in Activity.java, some keywords and methods involved are red. And when I move my mouse to it, it shows 'cannot resolve symbol xxx' or 'cannot resolve method xxx'
I've search this on stack overflow, and some said try 'invalidate and restart'. I did try, and when it restarted, progress 'indexing' appeared, and all the red words in Activity.java turned white. And I could see their declarations at that time. But when 'indexing' disappeared, all the work was done, the red words, which turned white for a few seconds, turned red again and I wasn't able to see their declarations again.

It's not possible for me to open every declaration of the keywords in those a few seconds, it's not just about this onCreate method, I think it's about all the sources when it comes to bottom implementation like this, but I've actually downloaded them. so any solutions for this kind of situation? Thanks very much!

Comment: You only need the SDK that matches your compileSDK version. The fact that it takes some time to index the SDK really depends on the hardware of your computer.

Comment: it is because I download so many version so I got this problem? But I've selected the one matches

Comment: I tried 'invalidate and restart', and when it showed 'indexing', everything was fine. but when indexing was finished, it went wrong again, wasn't able to go to their declarations again.

Comment: That explains why it takes a long time, yes. I don't know about your exact errors, though, but it needs to index and download the SDK sources before it can resolve any symbols and methods

Comment: I mean, I cannot go to the declarations of some keywords in Activity.java. I've downloaded the sources and selected the jdk embedded in android studio, and write down the correct version number in build.gradle. But it still did not work.   And this situation is kinda strange, because it did work during the 'indexing' progress, after it, things went wrong again.